# Sqrt is undefined, not sure why

Tags: python, nameerror, sqrt

I'm receiving this error and I'm not really sure why considering I've got the import math line there.

`NameError: name 'sqrt' is not defined`

```
import math
x = float(input())
y = float(input())
z = float(input())
print('{:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f}'.format(pow(x, z), pow(x, pow(y, z)), abs(x - y), sqrt(pow(x, z))))
```

**EDIT**: I was able to resolve the problem by using `math.sqrt` but I'm not sure why it's needed when the pow and abs functions work.

Comment: Look up imports. Either use `from math import sqrt` or `math.sqrt(...)`.

Comment: You have imported ```math``` but you haven't used it. ```sqrt``` is a function in that module. It is ```math.sqrt()```

Comment: as an aside sqrt is just `pow(x,0.5)`

Comment: Take a look at what functions are [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#built-in-funcs) (and realize that all other functions have to be either defined or imported).

Answer (score 4):

You have to import `sqrt` from `math`. Without importing `sqrt` you can't use it.
You can try this:

```
from math import sqrt
```

Or you can also do:

```
math.sqrt
```

`pow()` and `abs()` are predefined functions in python but `sqrt` is not  predefined in python. Alternatively, you can use `pow(N, 1/2)` as it is equivalent to `sqrt(N)`

Comment: I would not recommend `from [package] import *` as it pollutes the namespace. Image two package with the same name function but two different implementations, by importing `*` the later will overide the former.

Comment: It is also debugging nightmare if we import things as `*`.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently importing the entire math library and not actually using the sqrt function. You can fix this like so:

```
import math
x = float(input())
y = float(input())
z = float(input())
print('{:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f}'.format(pow(x, z), pow(x, pow(y, z)), abs(x - y), math.sqrt(pow(x, z))))
```